# How to publish a litElement

Tags: npm, polymer, web-component, lit-element

We are currently trying to create some Web Elements that we can share between different projects (Angular/React/Jquery...)

litElement seems like a good candidate for the task. We encounter this problem, however:

How do we make the changes/updates on the component we are working on available for a few dozen of consumers (if they want to). I heard that Polymer have some kind of repo like WebComponents.org. And we are already using NPM in our projects

So where can a litElement be published to for easy version/update management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [publish on NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) like other library. After that you can [publish on webcomponents.org](https://www.webcomponents.org/publish) to have more visibility.